# Connect Account with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How can I connect an account with Stripe as Developer ?

[image]

[image]

I found that connect needs express account. Express account need US address.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is recommended you have to toggle to use view test data to work as developer. You have to use developer/test data API keys to work as a developer.

Secondly, You can use account type custom to create connected account.

Also, there is no restriction to be based in US to used connected account with this account.

Comment: Thanks @chohan. How can I toggle ?

Comment: @abuabu You can see toggle option on left side of View Test Data. You acn find that on your dashboard at left side bar.